# Java - oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent - get changed row

Tags: java, sql, oracle, events, jdbc

I'm using oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent in order to get events notifications from my Oracle DB:

```
public class TListener implements DatabaseChangeListener
    {
    ...
    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent e)
    {
        ....

        synchronized( changeNotification ){
            changeNotification.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

And in Another place:

```
private void run(PropertiesConfiguration configuration) throws SQLException
{
OracleConnection conn = connect(configuration);     
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS,"true");
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION,"true");

DatabaseChangeRegistration dcr = conn.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(prop);

try
{
    // add the listenerr:
    TListener list = new TListener(this);
    dcr.addListener(list);

    // second step: add objects in the registration:
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


    // associate the statement with the registration:
    ((OracleStatement)stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from GTW_TX");
    while (rs.next()){}

    rs.close();
    stmt. Close (); 
}
```

My question: Is there a way to know which exactly rows where inserted\updated\changed\dalteted?

My purpose is to monitor the DB and do some actions when some specific events occurs, so **I want to be able to know the new\updated row values** in order to notify the Monitoring system (And to avoid full table scan with every event).

Important note: I do not have access to the DB beside the ability to "select", so triggers are not possible here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call [`registerDatabaseChangeNotification`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnectionWrapper.html#registerDatabaseChangeNotification_java_util_Properties_) with `OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS` set, you can use [`ROWID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ROWID.html)s:

Your `DatabaseChangeEvent` exposes a [`TableChangeDescription[] getTableChangeDescription()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeEvent.html#getTableChangeDescription__) function. If non-`null` one object per changed table is included and [`RowChangeDescription[] getRowChangeDescription()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/dcn/TableChangeDescription.html#getRowChangeDescription__) can be called, where you can finally get the [`ROWID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ROWID.html) by calling [`ROWID getRowid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/dcn/RowChangeDescription.html#getRowid__)

You may also need to evaluate the result of `getQueryChangeDescription()` where you also get `TableChangeDescription`-objects after calling `getTableChangeDescription()` on each alement of the array.

[`ROWID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ROWID.html) can be used according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/oraint4.htm) to select or update rows stored in an Oracle DB.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. I will publish my code when it's ready.

Comment: @TheConstructor I am working on the same project and I am trying to get row ID from database change notification. I am able to get RowID's using 'DatabaseChangeEvent e.toString();' which prints everything, but how do I get only RowID? I am unable to find 'RowChangeDescription[]getRowChangeDescription()' method as you have mentioned in the above comment. Please kindly help!!