# Oracle Database Changed Event - get Changed Row

Tags: java, events, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

```
class DCNDemoListener implements DatabaseChangeListener
    {
          String rid;
      DBChangeNotification demo;
      DCNDemoListener(DBChangeNotification dem)
      {
        demo = dem;
      }
      public void  onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent e)
      {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
//      System.out.println("DCNDemoListener: got an event ("+this+" running on thread "+t+")");
//      System.out.println(e.toString());
            TableChangeDescription[] tableChangeDescription = e.getTableChangeDescription();
            QueryChangeDescription[] queryChangeDescription = e.getQueryChangeDescription();
            RowChangeDescription[] rowChangeDescriptions = queryChangeDescription.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription(); // error here
            for (RowChangeDescription rowChangeDescription : rowChangeDescriptions) 
            {
              rowChangeDescription.getRowid();
            }              
  }
```

I am getting a error at `getTableChangeDescription()[0]` It says cannot find symbol. I have imported the class and ojdbc6.jar file correctly and I have checked the API doc as well and I don't know why I am getting error.

Basically, I am trying to pull ROWID to know where exactly insert/update/delete has been performed.

Looking at the previous [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820193/java-oracle-jdbc-dcn-databasechangeevent-get-changed-row), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699710/get-rowid-from-querychangedescription) by some other users has same steps to solve the issue but mine is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at these two lines:

```
QueryChangeDescription[] queryChangeDescription = e.getQueryChangeDescription();
RowChangeDescription[] rowChangeDescriptions = queryChangeDescription.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription(); // error here
```

You get the compilation error on `queryChangeDescription.getTableChangeDescription()`.  What is the type of the variable `queryChangeDescription`?

It's `QueryChangeDescription[]`.  That's an array type.

You're getting an error because the method `getTableChangeDescription` isn't on arrays.

I imagine you wanted to call the method on the first element of the array, not on the array itself.  If so, try

```
RowChangeDescription[] rowChangeDescriptions = queryChangeDescription[0].getTableChangeDescription()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) Been looking for it for hours for a simple thing, damn.